# geometric series in c, wrong solution

Tags: c, analysis, series, convergence

I'm getting a wrong solution for this series: `(-1/4)^(n+1)*(z-1)^n`

For `|z-1|<4` should the series tend to converge to `-1/3+z`

For `z=0.5` should be the solution `-2/7`, but if i try to plot with c, the result is 0...

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    double sum=0;
    int n;
    for(n=0;n<=100000;n++){
        sum+=pow((-1/4),(n+1)) * pow((0.5-1),n);
    }
    printf("sum= %f\n",sum);
}
```

Comment: The value of `-1/4` is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem right here:

```
    sum+=pow((-1/4),(n+1)) * pow((0.5-1),n);
```

`-1` is an integer literal, and so is `4`; hence, `(-1/4)` is `-0`, and not `-0.25` (which was probably what you wanted to use). Use floating point literals like `-1.0` if you want them in C!

Answer (score 0):

`-1/4` will result to `0` as its an integer division, use floats instead:

```
     (float)-1/4
```

Answer (score 0):

`1/4` refers to the euclidian division hence 0 obtained.
Use `sum+=pow((-1.0/4.0),(n+1)) * pow((0.5-1),n);` and you get the good results `sum= -0.285714`